# Como converter uma pilha de inteiros para char (string) em linguagem C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, char, stack

Poderiam me ajudar a converter esse código do tipo inteiro para `char`(string) ? Estou iniciando e tenho muita dificuldade com ponteiros. Creio que seja isso que está acontecendo. Já tentei trocar o tipo `INT` por `CHAR`, mas não roda corretamente. Na posição dos índices ou aparece `NULL` ou outro valor incorreto. Preciso que aparece cinco frase ao invés de inteiros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 5

int pilha[TAM] = {0,0,0,0,0};
int topo = 0;

void lista_elementos(){
    int i;
    printf("\n==============Pilha Atual===============\n");//
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf("-");
        printf("|%d|", pilha[i]);
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n\nTopo: %d", topo);
    printf("\n\n");
}

void push(){
    int val;
    printf("informe o valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    if (topo < TAM){
        pilha[topo] = val;
        topo+= 1;
        lista_elementos();
    }else{
        printf("Pilha esta cheia: \n");
    }
}

void pop(){
    printf("Removendo elementos:\n");
    if (topo >= 0){
        pilha[topo-1] = 0;
        topo = topo + 1;
        lista_elementos();
    }else{
        printf("Pilha esta vazia...\n");
    }
}

void clear(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        pilha[i] = 0;
    }
    topo = 0;
}

int main(){
    
    int opcao = 0;
    
    do{
        printf("\nSelecione a opcao: \n\n"); 
        printf("[1] - Inserir (push)\n");
        printf("[2] - Remover (pop)\n");
        printf("[3] - Lista:\n");
        printf("[4] - Limpar a pilha: \n");
        printf("[-1] - Sair: \n\n");
        printf("Escolha opcao:\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        
        
        switch(opcao){
            case 1:
                push();
                break;
            case 2:
                pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                lista_elementos();
                break;
            case 4:
                clear();
                break;
            case -1:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalida: \n");
        }
        
    }while(opcao != -1);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, `char` não é `string`. `char` é apenas (supostamente) um caractere e ele tem tamanho fixo de 8 bits.

Uma string é um conjunto de `char`, algo como `char string[100]`. Nesse caso estou assumindo que haja um tamanho máximo para a string, caso contrário seria um pouco diferente (alocações dinamicas, mallocs etc).

*Como seu código não tem qualquer alocação dinamica e afins, estou assumindo que não é isso que deseja.*

---

Primeiro, altere o vetor para:

```
char pilha[5][256];
```

Com isso temos 5 espaços para um texto de até 255 caracteres (assumindo cada caracter um byte, o que não é sempre verdade).

---

Depois, você deve usar este valor para receber as coisas do `scanf`, que decidi alterar para `scanf_s` por razões de segurança:

```
void push(){
    if (topo < TAM){
        printf("informe o valor: ");
        scanf_s("%s", &pilha[topo][0], 255); // << &pilha[topo][0] como entrada
        topo += 1;
        lista_elementos();
    }else{
        printf("Pilha esta cheia: \n");
    }
}
```

Note que passamos o valor como `&pilha[topo][0]`, ou seja pegamos o ponteiro do primeiro caracter do array, e o `scanf` vai escrever nele.

---

Para resetar o conteúdo usamos o `memset`:

```
void pop(){
    if (topo > 0){
        printf("Removendo elementos:\n");
        memset(&pilha[topo-1][0], 0, 256); // << memset
        topo = topo - 1;  // << No seu código isto está errado também ;)
        lista_elementos();
    }else{
        printf("Pilha esta vazia...\n");
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, o `memset` vai definir todos os 256 elementos do nosso array (que começa em &pilha[topo-1][0]) para `0`. *Ou seja, é um mesmo que um `for`/`while` usando `pilha[topo-1][i] = 0` em toda sua extensão.*

---

No final temos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

#define TAM 5

char pilha[5][256];
int topo = 0;

void lista_elementos(){
    int i;
    printf("\n==============Pilha Atual===============\n");//
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf("-");
        printf("|%s|", pilha[i]);
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n\nTopo: %d", topo);
    printf("\n\n");
}

void push(){
    if (topo < TAM){
        printf("informe o valor: ");
        scanf_s("%s", &pilha[topo][0], 255);
        topo += 1;
        lista_elementos();
    }else{
        printf("Pilha esta cheia: \n");
    }
}

void pop(){
    if (topo > 0){
        printf("Removendo elementos:\n");
        memset(&pilha[topo-1][0], 0, 256);
        topo = topo - 1;
        lista_elementos();
    }else{
        printf("Pilha esta vazia...\n");
    }
}

void clear(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        memset(&pilha[i][0], 0, 256);
    }
    topo = 0;
}

int main(){

    int opcao = 0;

    do{
        printf("\nSelecione a opcao: \n\n");
        printf("[1] - Inserir (push)\n");
        printf("[2] - Remover (pop)\n");
        printf("[3] - Lista:\n");
        printf("[4] - Limpar a pilha: \n");
        printf("[-1] - Sair: \n\n");
        printf("Escolha opcao:\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);


        switch(opcao){
            case 1:
                push();
                break;
            case 2:
                pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                lista_elementos();
                break;
            case 4:
                clear();
                break;
            case -1:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalida: \n");
        }

    }while(opcao != -1);

}
```

Comment: Rafael, o feedback foi construtivo. Como você poderia empilhar numa nova pilha os valores que foram desempilhados pela função pop ? Poderia comentar por favor? Ou, seja, desempilho e empilho novamente , item a item. Abs

Comment: @JoséFraga, não sei quem é Rafael, e isto parece ter sido copiado de outro lugar. Mas, para responder, basta entender como o código atual funciona, porque é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Cara, desculpe, eu respondi a pessoa errada.